# gettin mysql 1064 error while insert into

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064, insert-into

like i said in the header i'm getting that annoying error and it showed up from nowhere and i couldnt find a solution from internet.

anyway here is my code

```
$kayitsorgu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `kresler`(`il_no`, `ilce_no`, `uye_adi`, 
                `kat_no`, `icerik`, `icerik2`, `premic1`, `thubnail`, `kres_ad`, `kres_adres`, 
                `kres_mail`, `tel1`, `fax`, `kres_drc`, `anao`, `oz1`, `oz2`, `oz3`, 
                `oz4`, `oz5`, `oz6`, `oz7`, `oz8`, `oz9`, `oz10`) 
                VALUES ($il_no,$ilce_no,$uye_adi,$kat_no,$icerik,$icerik2,$premic1,$thubnail,
                $kres_ad,$kres_adres,$kres_mail,$tel1,$fax,$kres_drc,$anao,$oz1,$oz2,
                $oz3,$oz4,$oz5,$oz6,$oz7,$oz8,$oz9,$oz10)");
```

please help me i'm trying to fix this like 2-3 days.

Comment: 1064 means you have a syntax error in your SQL statement. Since you haven't posted your actual SQL query (we can't guess what you might have in all those PHP variables), there's no way to answer you. My guess is that some of those variables contain strings that break the SQL query.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@444444444.com,555555555,555555555555,2,0,3 - 5,15:00 - 05:00,10 - 1000,4111,111' at line 1 this is the actual error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a shot:

```
$frag1="INSERT INTO kresler(il_no, ilce_no, uye_adi,kat_no, icerik, icerik2, premic1, thubnail, kres_ad,";
$frag2=" kres_adres, kres_mail, tel1, fax, kres_drc, anao, oz1, oz2, oz3, oz4, oz5, oz6, oz7, oz8, oz9, oz10)";
$frag3=" VALUES ('$il_no','$ilce_no','$uye_adi','$kat_no','$icerik','$icerik2','$premic1','$thubnail',";
$frag4="'$kres_ad','$kres_adres','$kres_mail','$tel1','$fax','$kres_drc','$anao','$oz1','$oz2',";
$frag5="'$oz3','$oz4','$oz5','$oz6','$oz7','$oz8','$oz9','$oz10')";

$exec_me=$frag1.$frag2.$frag3.$frag4.$frag5;

$kayitsorgu = mysql_query($exec_me);
```

when run, $exec_me=

```
put here
```

error message:

> put here

Comment: i tried but still getting this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@444444444.com,555555555,555555555555,2,0,3 - 5,15:00 - 05:00,10 - 1000,4111,111' at line 1 page

Comment: can you echo $exec_me and edit and plop at end of my pseudo answer

Comment: this is what is coming from echo of exec_me " INSERT INTO kresler(il_no, ilce_no, uye_adi,kat_no, icerik, icerik2, premic1, thubnail, kres_ad, kres_adres, kres_mail, tel1, fax, kres_drc, anao, oz1, oz2, oz3, oz4, oz5, oz6, oz7, oz8, oz9, oz10) VALUES (4,71,fffff,6,dfdfdffd,dffddffddf,aaaaaa,krthub/traf.png,dfdfff,55555555555555,55555555555@444444444.com,555555555,555555555555,2,0,3 - 5,15:00 - 05:00,10 - 1000,4111,1111,1,1,1,1,1)"

Comment: sorry i had a senior moment. reload my answer. i had forgotten the single quotes, review it now

Comment: ok, mark answer and up down, check marked, and move on to mysqli. good luck

Comment: i checked it but what is mysqli?

Comment: the mysql_* functions you are using are deprecated and no longer supported (though will work surely for years). There are scads of reasons not to use mysql_* anymore. Time to move on to `mysqli` or preferably `pdo`. see here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info

Comment: you will need to re-do connections and re-jigger code. Norbert showed you the 25s block in his answer. Try to at least get into mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the query it is possibly also a lack of quoting the data correctly.

Start using mysqli prepared statements to prevent mistakes and help debugging:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `kresler`(`il_no`, `ilce_no`, `uye_adi`, 
            `kat_no`, `icerik`, `icerik2`, `premic1`, `thubnail`, `kres_ad`, `kres_adres`, 
            `kres_mail`, `tel1`, `fax`, `kres_drc`, `anao`, `oz1`, `oz2`, `oz3`, 
            `oz4`, `oz5`, `oz6`, `oz7`, `oz8`, `oz9`, `oz10`) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
            ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
//You have 25 variables, I made them all strings here (so 25 x s)
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssssss",
  $il_no,$ilce_no,$uye_adi,$kat_no,
  $icerik,$icerik2,$premic1,$thubnail,
  $kres_ad,$kres_adres,$kres_mail,
  $tel1,$fax,$kres_drc,$anao,$oz1,$oz2,
  $oz3,$oz4,$oz5,$oz6,$oz7,$oz8,$oz9,$oz10);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: i got this error from your code now Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/barontamtam/public_html/betak/admin/act.php on line 78

Comment: Tamer, this is where you should be at shortly with your code. It will require a little re-write. I would go for a jump to `pdo`. Regardless, get away from mysql_* as I mentioned at the end of my comments to you

Comment: Sorry, had a $query instead of $stmt on line 2. Anyway: The chance that this will run at once, is certainly not 100%: You have a pretty long insert statement, so the chance of a mistake in there stays: 25 variables: Look a bit into database design too, there is most likely a smarter method of setting up this table).